# Working nativescript-vue with typescript and hot module reload

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue, webpack-hmr

After creating a project using the "view init nativescript-view/view-cli-template app" command with the TypeScript option, the Hot Module Reload does not work at all.
I am using version 6.0 of nativescript.
How to configure the project to run the module "HMR"?

Comment: appears to be an issue with NativeScript v8 as well